# Can I pass a pointer to a class object into a function? What is the proper syntax?

Tags: function, class, pointers, object, argument-passing

I'm having trouble passing a pointer to a class object into a function.

```
myFunction(fruit apple)
{
...
}
```

```
 int main()
    {
        fruit *apple = new fruit;

        myFunction(&apple);
    }
```

After that the compiler tells me that it can't convert the argument from fruit to string. I don't understand what a string has to do with any of this. Is it possible to pass a pointer of an object as a function argument?

Answer (score 1):

May be it has to do with your definition of the fruit class. Below is the correct implementation of what you are trying to achieve here.

```
myFunction (fruit *apple)
{
...
}

int main()
{
   fruit *apple = new fruit;
   myFunction(apple);
}
```

In your code, apple is already a pointer to an object of type fruit. So you don't need to take its address again using the ampersand & operator. If your requirement was to pass a pointer to a pointer to an object (which I doubt is what you need), then your main() function was ok but myFunction would be defined as follows:

```
myFunction (fruit **apple)
{
...
}
```

Comment: This was helpful but the MVS still thinks that the argument is supposed to be a string. 
"Cannot convert argument 2 from 'fruit' to 'std::string' on the "myFunction(apple);" line.

Comment: Need to look at more of your code; can you post the complete thing, including the line number where compiler is raising the error?

Comment: I later realized what was wrong. I forgot to update my header file that linked to the other cpp file with my functions in it.